# Django not validating Class-Based Views correctly

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-class-based-views, django-validation

In a Django 1.9 online learning app, I have a form that I am making using the generic class-based view `CreateView` as wells as some other mixins. In the form the 'owner' is able to create a new course, but upon form submission I get the following error:

```
IntegrityError at /course/create/
NOT NULL constraint failed: courses_course.owner_id
```

I realize that I am getting the error, because the form isn't saving the `owner`, which is part of the `Course` model. And I know the owner isn't saving because the app is not even entering my `form_valid` method in `OwnerEditMixin` class. (My console is not printing the `form validating ...` message in the method.)

Here is the code from my view:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from .models import Course
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, \
    PermissionRequiredMixin


class OwnerMixin(object):

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(OwnerMixin, self).get_queryset()
        return qs.filter(owner=self.request.user)


class OwnerEditMixin(object):

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print('form validating ...')
        form.instance.owner = self.request.user
        return super(OwnerEditMixin, self).form_valid(form)


class OwnerCourseMixin(OwnerMixin, LoginRequiredMixin):
    model = Course


class OwnerCourseEditMixin(OwnerCourseMixin, OwnerEditMixin):
    fields = ['subject', 'title', 'slug', 'overview']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('manage_course_list')
    template_name = 'courses/manage/course/form.html'


class CourseCreateView(OwnerCourseEditMixin, CreateView,
                       PermissionRequiredMixin):
    permission_required = 'courses.add_course'
```

The relevant template code is here:

```
    <form action="." method="post">
        {{ form.as_p }}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p><input type="submit" value="Save course"></p>
    </form>
```

Any ideas for why the class-based view isn't calling my `form_valid` method?

PS: I followed the example for class-based views form validation from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user

Comment: Your inheritance is *really* complicated. Does it work if you simplify it to `class CourseCreateView(OwnerEditMixin, CreateView):`?

Comment: Ah thank you! It wasn't actually that change that did it, but as I was playing around with the inheritance I realized that I need to have `class OwnerEditMixin(OwnerMixin):` so that it inherits from `OwnerMixin`. That was the only change needed! It works now :)

Although I'm not really sure why that worked?